# How to automatically create series number when csv_read()?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I get one data csv file from github and use pd.csv_read() to read it. it would automatically create series number like this.

```
    label  repeattrips        id  offer_id  never_bought_company  \
0       1            5     86246   1208251                     0   
1       1           16     86252   1197502                     0   
2       0            0  12682470   1197502                     1   
3       0            0  12996040   1197502                     1   
4       0            0  13089312   1204821                     0   
5       0            0  13179265   1197502                     1   
6       0            0  13251776   1200581                     0
```

but when I create my csv file and read it.

```
   label  gender  age_range  action0  action1  action2  action3  first  \
0      0       2          1        0        1        0        2      1   
0      0       4          0        0        1        0        1      1   
0      1       2          8        0        1        0        9      1   
1      0       2          0        0        1        0        1      1   
0      1       5          0        0        1        0        1      1   
0      1       5          0        0        1        0        1      1
```

the label is regarded as series number in my output.

If I create a series number in the front of every line of my data, still didn't solve the problem. like this:

```
      label  gender  age_range  action0  action1  action2  action3  first  \
0  0      0       2          1        0        1        0        2      1   
1  0      0       4          0        0        1        0        1      1   
2  0      1       2          8        0        1        0        9      1   
3  1      0       2          0        0        1        0        1      1   
4  0      1       5          0        0        1        0        1      1   
5  0      1       5          0        0        1        0        1      1   
6  0      0       7          5        0        1        0        6      1   
7  0      0       7          1        0        1        0        2      1
```

I don't know if I saved it right. My csv data is like this (added series number) and the github file looks similar format as well:

```
label gender age_range action0 action1 action2 action3 first second third fourth sirstrate secondrate thirdrate fourthrate total_cat total_brand total_time total_items users_appear users_items users_cats users_brands users_times users_action0 users_action1 users_action2 users_action3 merchants_appear merchants_items merchants_cats merchants_brands merchants_times merchants_action0 merchants_action1 merchants_action2 merchants_action3
0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 2 1 1 0 0.0224719101124 0.5 0.5 0 1 1 1 1 89 71 22 45 17 87 0 2 0 46 34 11 16 3 38 4 2 2 
1 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0.00469483568075 0.0232558139535 0.0232558139535 0.0 1 1 1 1 213 102 47 44 30 170 0 36 7 103 58 25 23 6 81 0 22 0 
2 0 1 2 8 0 1 0 9 1 1 0 0.0157342657343 0.0181818181818 0.0181818181818 0.0 2 2 1 5 572 393 111 158 60 517 0 15 40 119 70 24 20 17 106 6 7 0 
3 1 0 2 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0.0142857142857 0.0769230769231 0.0769230769231 0.0 1 1 1 1 70 33 19 15 15 57 0 11 2 27 17 11 15 11 18 0 2 7 
4 0 1 5 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0.025641025641 0.2 0.2 0.0 1 1 1 1 39 32 16 29 14 34 0 4 1 133 88 26 25 11 128 0 5 0
```

one line in one blank, rather than every item of one line in one blank.

Could you tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide code to get more substantive help since it's unclear why you're facing a problem. For example, copying the data you pasted at the bottom reads in just fine with `pd.read_clipboard()`, and `pd.read_csv()` should also work fine as long as you set it up with a space separator:

```
In [2]: pd.read_clipboard()
Out[2]:
   label  gender  age_range  action0  action1  action2  action3  first  \
0      0       0          2        1        0        1        0      2
1      0       0          4        0        0        1        0      1
2      0       1          2        8        0        1        0      9
3      1       0          2        0        0        1        0      1
4      0       1          5        0        0        1        0      1

   second  third        ...          users_action3  merchants_appear  \
0       1      1        ...                      0                46
1       1      1        ...                      7               103
2       1      1        ...                     40               119
3       1      1        ...                      2                27
4       1      1        ...                      1               133

   merchants_items  merchants_cats  merchants_brands  merchants_times  \
0               34              11                16                3
1               58              25                23                6
2               70              24                20               17
3               17              11                15               11
4               88              26                25               11

   merchants_action0  merchants_action1  merchants_action2  merchants_action3
0                 38                  4                  2                  2
1                 81                  0                 22                  0
2                106                  6                  7                  0
3                 18                  0                  2                  7
4                128                  0                  5                  0

[5 rows x 37 columns]
```

Comment: I find my end of every line is `+','+'\n'`. That's the reason lol